# Handling authorization with IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, authorization, identityserver4, identity

I'm extremely confused on how to use a centralized IDP with both authentication and authorization. The architecture for my project was to be a single web API and one React client. I wanted to keep things structured out into microservices just to try something more modern, but I'm having major issues with the centralized identity, as many others have.

My goal is fairly simple. User logs in, selects a tenant from a list of tenants that they have access to, and then they are redirected to the client with roles and a "tid" or tenant id claim which is just the GUID of the selected company.

The Microsoft prescribed way to add identity in my scenario is IdentityServer, so I started with that. Everything was smooth sailing until I discovered the inner workings of the tokens. While some others have issues adding permissions, the authorization logic in my application is very simple and roles would suffice. While I would initially be fine with roles refreshing naturally via expiration, they must immediately update whenever my users select a different tenant to "log in" to. However, the problem is that I cannot refresh these claims when the user changes tenants without logging out. Essentially, I tried mixing authorization with authentication and hit a wall.

It seems like I have two options:

1. Obtain the authorization information from a separate provider, or even an endpoint on the identity server itself, like /user-info but for authorization information. This ends up adding a huge overhead, but the actual boilerplate for the server and for the client is minimal. This is similar to how the OSS version of PolicyServer does it, although I do not know how their paid implementation is. My main problem here is that both the client and resource (API) will need this information. How could I avoid N requests per interaction (where N is the number of resources/clients)?
2. Implement some sort of custom state and keep a store of users who need their JWTs refreshed. Check these and return some custom response to the caller, which then uses custom js client code to refresh the token on this response. This is a huge theory and, even if it is plausible, still introduces state and kind of invalidates the point of JWTs while requiring a large amount of custom code.

So, I apologize for the long post but this is really irking me. I do not NEED to use IdentityServer or JWTs, but I would like to at least have a React front-end. What options do I have for up-to-date tenancy selection and roles? Right when I was willing to give in and implement an authorization endpoint that returns fresh data, I realized I'd be calling it both at the API and client *every* request. Even with cached data, that's a lot of overhead just in pure http calls. Is there some alternative solution that would work here? Could I honestly just use a cookie with authorization information that is secure and updated only when necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using remote gRPC calls for the authorization. You can see more at https://github.com/Perustaja/PermissionServerDemo

I don't like to accept my own answer here but I think my solution and thoughts on it in the repository will be good for anyone thinking about possible solutions to handing stale JWT authorization information.

Answer (score 1):

It becomes confusing when you want to use IdentityServer as-is for *user authorization*. Keep concerns seperated.

As [commented](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/#comment-131079) by Dominick Baier:

> Yes – we recommend to use IdentityServer for end-user authentication,
> federation and API access control.
>
> PolicyServer is our recommendation for user authorization.

Option 1 seems the recommended option. So if you decide to go for option 1:

The OSS version of the PolicyServer will suffice for handling the requests. But instead of using a [json config file](https://github.com/PolicyServer/PolicyServer.Local/blob/master/src/Host/Startup.cs#L33):

```
// this sets up the PolicyServer client library and policy provider
// - configuration is loaded from appsettings.json
services.AddPolicyServerClient(Configuration.GetSection("Policy"))
    .AddAuthorizationPermissionPolicies();
```

get the information from an endpoint. Add caching to improve performance.

In order to allow centralized access, you can either create a seperate policy server or extend IdentityServer with user authorization endpoints. Use [extension grants](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html#example-simple-delegation-using-an-extension-grant) to access the user authorization endpoints, because you may want to distinguish between client and api.

The json configuration is local. The new endpoint will need it's own data store where it can read the user claims. In order to allow centralized information, add information about where the permissions can be used. Personally I use the scope to model the permissions, because both client and api know the scope.

Final step is to add admin UI or endpoints to maintain the user authorization.

Comment: It seems like the real question is storing JWT state to force a refresh vs making a call every request to retrieve authorization info. First seems hacky and second seems inefficient. I'm not really worried about the time to complete the request, just about the load on the server. I just tripled my calls, but the second option still seems hacky and against the point of JWTs.

Comment: @perustaja I will update the answer later, but for now: in my setup the JWT doens't contain user authorization claims. User authorization has a different source. So there is no reason to store the JWT state because the user (identity) and client authorization do not change. Even when the context changes, e.g. a different tenant, the user authorization doesn't change. Only the view on the user authorization changes. You can manage this by adding a discriminator, the tenant.

Comment: I understand, how do you think the discriminator should be added? My plan currently is when the user accesses the portal, it sets its SelectedOrg property. On each page load in the SPA, it calls the authorization info endpoint (roles, perms, selected org) with the id_token's sub GUID. Once it gets this info, subsequent requests are made to someapi/organizations/{selectedorg}/... This handles some edge cases but personally my ideal is multi-tab support so a user can have 1 tenant's data in one tab and the other in the next. That part seems entirely client-based to me. Appreciate the feedback